# Fastest growth rate of sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series

[image]

Sorry about the weird page formatting.

So somehow this will use linear algebra to be solved but I'm a bit confused on what to do. I see that (0,0) will work. But c can't be 0. I also see that (1,1) AND (-1,-1) work. I'm mostly confused about how to find the last part. The fastest way that this can grow...

Comment: Instead of apologizing, you could rewrite the question using MathJax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the first question you supposed to find that:
$x_n = (x_1-1)2^n+x_0$

so the grow rate is 2, when $x_1>1$

Comment: Isn't the general solution $(2^n-1)(x_1-x_0)+x_0$, and the condition $x_1>x_0$ ?

Comment: Okay yeah I just got that too. I was thinking about the problem wrong. I didn't realize that it would converge on a constant geometric growth like that.